# How can I stop terminal and firefox from launching on startup?

Tags: xubuntu, startup, startup-applications

Hi everyone and first of all, thanks for your attention - I appreciate it!

Here my problem. I'm new to linux, although I'm a web programmer so command line doesn't look weird to me, and I'm now running Xubuntu. I have made several configurations and installations and it's now working fine, except for this weird thing: terminal window and firefox browser are launching as soon as I log into my account. Does anybody know how such thing could be happening?

I have rebooted several times, logged in/off as well, but both terminal and firefox window come up automatically every time I start a session.

Has anybody run into this before? How can i find a solution to make those apps NOT start on startup?

Thanks again! Hope someone can help me hehe

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @Matthew but that wasn't really the case this time. I'll keep an eye on those settings though for a possible similar event in the future!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two possible reasons why the application is started: It is saved in the last session or it is listed in the auto started applications. Follow 1 of the two steps below to get rid of the applications.

- Start the xfce4-autostart-editor and remove the application(s). You can also manually delete those files in ~/Desktop/Autostart and ~/.config/autostart.
- Most of the time closing all the applications and save your session when you logout is sufficient. If this doesn't work, remove the content of the ~/.cache/sessions/ directory when you're not logged in. And if you don't want xfce remember every session you should turn off (uncheck) “Automatically save session on logout” in Settings Manager → Sessions and Startup (tab General)

Reference: [1](http://wiki.xfce.org/faq).

Comment: Thanks a lot @desgua! You helped me find **the solution: I just had to remove all files in ~/.cache/sessions/** and that's it - no unwanted apps loading on session startup anymore.

Comment: I'm glad it worked :-)

Comment: There is another checkbox to save the session in the logout dialog. In my case I had to uncheck that one. I then had to delete ~/.cache/sessions to get rid of the last session that was saved.

Comment: What is this xfce4-autostart-editor? It's not installed in 13.04 and it's not in the repos. Has it another name?

Comment: You should ask it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks, `cd ~/.cache/sessions/` and `rm -r *` solved it.

Comment: "remove ... directory when you're not logged in" *SADLY*, I only have one user and I pretty much can't do that. Perhaps "sudo init 1", tho that seems extreme. And there's no reference to Firefox under either ~/Desktop or ~/.cache/autostart. Oh, no "sessions" dir anyway. Did someone think this autostart stuff was a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to open startup apps and see what is there, might be as easy as that,
**if** those apps are in startup, you can just remove them

Another option to consider is ubuntu tweak, it can help you regulate how things start

Comment: Thanks @dewb! I've checked which apps were opening at startup but neither Firefox or xterminal (xfce terminal) were in the list (I have posted what worked out for me under @desgua's answer).

Comment: About xubuntu, well, xfce runs much faster than gnome for me (I'm running linux in a notebook) and since xubuntu comes with it by default, I picked it up :)